# Are four gang plastic boxes stackable in a wall?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I would even be willing to go side by side but I would like to stay with the four gang sizes.

I am hoping this would pass code and would prefer to stack so if there is someone that knows if it is okay or if it is okay with workarounds - I would love the input.

My family and I are putting in electric boxes in [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_insulated_panel) walls and that is no fun to begin with much less start down the wrong path, scoop out and have to put foam back in.

Comment: The fact that you're using a SIP is good info.  Under the circumstances I would consult with the SIP manufacturer.  The most pertinent question here in my mind is, will removing that much surface area from a sip's face compromise it's strength significantly?

Comment: Boxes can be stacked so to speak without violating code (NEC). It should be noted though that stacking, or aligning, a switch box won't work unless you have a high dollar custom switch plate. The box is not as large as the switch plate so if you put any two boxes side by side, unless it is a metal cut in box designed to do so, you'll have collision issues. Even if you used a metal cut in you'd still end up with a single box ganged to the size you determine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it wouldn't be allowed under code, but any question like this can only be answered by your permitting authority. My experience is that inspectors are happy to answer such questions.